# I have ubuntu 14.04 on my laptop, i want to dual boot windows 8.1 alogside it

Tags: dual-boot

I previously had windows 8.1 preinstalled on my pc, later i dual booted it with ubuntu 14.04, then i later accidentally removed my windows, currently my pc boots from UEFI , where i still have "windows boot loader" as an option. i have completely formatted all the space and currently have just ubuntu 14.04 on my pc.
my partiotions are:
1.home (linux filesystem)
2.root (linux filesystem)
3.swap
4.A (NTFS)
5.B (NTFS)
I made two huge ntfs partitions so that i could later install windows on them.
it would be really helpful if you could guide me through this.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I install Windows after I've installed Ubuntu?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/6317/how-can-i-install-windows-after-ive-installed-ubuntu)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already have Ubuntu 14.04. Good.
Now Create a new primary NTFS partition size about 50G and make flag as "boot" with the Gparted Software in Ubuntu. Write down the partition name and number and size.
Now  install windows 8.1 on this specific NTFS partition using your windows 8.1 CD.
Ubuntu will appear to disappear temporarily. Do not worry. It is still there on the Ubuntu specific preserved partition.Note the Ubuntu partition name & size & number.
Now download and Install the free Easybcd bootloader from the site below and follow the steps to add a new entry Linux  to windows 8.1 boot loader.

http://download.cnet.com/Partition-Wizard-Home-Edition/3000-2094_4-10962200.html?part=dl-6285158&subj=dl&tag=button

Save.
Reboot and select either windows 8.1 or Ubuntu from the boot list.
It worked for me.
If it works or helps click on the like button to guide other users.
sserve2006